# Use Google Cloud Storage Bucket with GCE LoadBalancer... not in host and paths

Tags: nginx, kubernetes, google-cloud-storage, google-kubernetes-engine, kubernetes-ingress

I'm trying to route traffic to a static bucket on GCE. Right now I am using ingress, but have found the docs for Google here:

https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/load-balancing/http/adding-a-backend-bucket-to-content-based-load-balancing

I get all the way through, but cannot select the 'backend bucket' while in the hosts and paths menu doing the url mapping... even though it is listed under the backend buckets. The 'Backend Services' options can be selected, but the backend buckets menu is disabled. Does anyone know of a better tutorial, or a better way to route traffic to a bucket for static content?

Can I specify it in the ingress yaml maybe?

Comment: I would say the documentation you are looking at is the best documentation at the moment for achieving your goal. Are you trying to just add a new bucket route path to an existing load balancer or  you are creating a load balancer just for bucket redirection   ?

Comment: I created one via ingress, so it's already maybe I should create a load balancer specifically rather than an ingress one? Lol

Comment: Yes I would definitely suggest create a dedicated load balancer because at the moment there is not option to create an host path rule from  ingress as per this bug https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-gce/issues/33

Comment: Awesome, I'll definitely try it and let you know. So ingess, then direct the static path to the dedicated Load Balancer you think?

Comment: Yep that's what I meant !

Answer (score 5):

It looks like this will be available in kubernetes **1.19**

Note, however, that 1.19 isn't available on GKE yet (as of the time of this post) but regardless I thought this would be useful information for people landing here. When 1.19 is available, I'll try it out and update this answer.

For a preview of how this will look in config, the [pull request](https://github.com/kubernetes/website/pull/21590/files#diff-56bb969f0c219fb744bcbcb43e40335a) for the feature includes an example

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: ingress-resource-backend
spec:
  defaultBackend:
    resource:
      apiGroup: k8s.example.com
      kind: StorageBucket
      name: static-assets
  rules:
    - http:
        paths:
          - path: /icons
            pathType: ImplementationSpecific
            backend:
              resource:
                apiGroup: k8s.example.com
                kind: StorageBucket
                name: icon-assets
```

Comment: For anyone stumbling upon this answer: No, 1.19 did not ship with this feature and neither did 1.20. Maybe k8s has the API for it but GKE definitely doesn't support it. The real value for`k8s.example.com` is still missing and we need that to be able to use the resource type :/

Comment: Will this be supported with the Gateway Controller?

Answer (score 3):

Specifying "backend buckets" is not supported on GCE Ingress yaml spec currently.

If you modify a load balancer created by the Ingress controller to route some of the traffic to a backend bucket (by editing its URL map), your changes will be periodically overwritten by the Ingress controller.

Your only option is likely to create a separate load balancer for your "backend bucket".

Comment: should this work out? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55779048/kubernetes-external-loadbalancer-pointing-to-cloud-bucket

Answer (score 1):

If you enable [ConfigConnector](https://cloud.google.com/config-connector/docs), you can use it to refer to resources that were created outside of GKE from resources within GKE (e.g. your Ingress). You'd use an [External reference](https://cloud.google.com/config-connector/docs/how-to/creating-resource-references#external_references) to do so.

Alternately, if you'd like to create/manage the buckets from within GKE, you can do so using the [StorageBucket](https://cloud.google.com/config-connector/docs/reference/resource-docs/storage/storagebucket) custom resource definition.

Here's what this might look like (update: I tried this using GKE 1.20 and it doesn't work):

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: ingress-resource-backend
spec:
  defaultBackend:
    resource:
      apiGroup: resourcemanager.cnrm.cloud.google.com
      kind: StorageBucket
      name: static-assets
  rules:
    - http:
        paths:
          - path: /icons
            pathType: ImplementationSpecific
            backend:
              resource:
                apiGroup: resourcemanager.cnrm.cloud.google.com
                kind: StorageBucket
                name: icon-assets
```

Comment: Is there an option to use ConfigConnector with Autopilot? Couldn't really find a way to get it to work