# Kubernetes ingress-nginx LoadBalancer pointing to cloud bucket

Tags: kubernetes, load-balancing, gcloud, nginx-ingress

I use [nginx-ingress-controller:0.24.1](https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/releases/tag/nginx-0.24.1) ([Inspired by](https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/issues/1809))

I would like to set a DNS A record to LB IP address, so it would connect it to the Google cloud public bucket (`my-back-end-bucket`) that has public index.html in the root AND to the back-end by another url rule.

```
kind: Service
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: ingress-nginx
  namespace: ingress-nginx
  labels:
    app.kubernetes.io/name: ingress-nginx
    app.kubernetes.io/part-of: ingress-nginx
spec:
  externalTrafficPolicy: Local
  type: LoadBalancer
  selector:
    app.kubernetes.io/name: ingress-nginx
    app.kubernetes.io/part-of: ingress-nginx
  ports:
    - name: http
      port: 80
      targetPort: http
    - name: https
      port: 443
      targetPort: https

---

kind: Service
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: google-storage-buckets-service
  namespace: ingress-nginx
spec:
  type: ExternalName
  externalName: storage.googleapis.com

---
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: proxy-assets-ingress
  namespace: ingress-nginx
  annotations:
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /my.bucket.com
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/secure-backends: "true"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/upstream-vhost: "storage.googleapis.com"
spec:
  rules:
    - http:
        paths:
          - path: /*
            backend:
              serviceName: google-storage-buckets-service
              servicePort: 443
          - path: /c/
            backend:
              serviceName: hello-world-service
              servicePort: 8080
```

By reaching https://my.ip.add.ress/c - got both outputs: **Hello, world! bucket content.**

**"Hello, world!"** form the **hello-world-service**

**"bucket content"** from the **bucket**' index.html file

Question: how to make it work so, that by **ip/** - I got a bucket content
and by **ip/c** - back-end response content ?

Comment: Why you need Kubernetes for that? It can achieved without Kubernetes: https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/hosting-static-website

Comment: because: 1. I need https support, it seems possible only with a load balancer in place 2. the static content will be just a little part of the bigger system based on URL rules it would redirect part of the traffic to the bucket that would store some static frontend

Comment: You can use Google Cloud Load Balancer to serve content from a public GCS bucket directly. See https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/https/adding-a-backend-bucket-to-content-based-load-balancing

Comment: I would like to use ingress, NOT just load balancer. it is 2019! :)

Answer (score 1):

You can split your ingress into two where one defines `path: /*` with necessary annotation and another ingress that defines `path: /c/`.

The problem with your single ingress is that its annotations that you want to apply to `path: /*` only gets applied to other paths as well.

Comment: original post on [github](https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/issues/1809)